Footnote placement at the end of quote environment outside of quotation marks
I'm currently using the quote-environment and the footcite command, to display the citation-footnotes at the end of the quote environment. Now I have added quotationsmarks by amending the quote environment like this:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{needspace}
\renewenvironment{quote}
               {
               \list{\Large\glqq\hspace{-0.4em} \normalsize} 
               {\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item\relax\small\sl\ignorespaces
                \needspace{4\baselineskip}
                }
               {\Large\grqq\normalsize \endlist}

\begin{document} 


\lipsum[1]

\begin{quote}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{citationsreference}
\end{quote}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}

Now the quote-block looks like this:

Now the footnote is inside the quotes, which I added in the redefinition of the quote environment. Does anyone have an idea, how i can, without manually going through all the instances, change this, so that the footnote is outside, i.e. to the right, of the quotation mark? Any untidy etc idea is welcome.

Consider the following rather untidy idea: you can locally redefine \footnote to not print directly, but store the contents, and show the footnote after the \grqq using a renamed copy of the original \footnote command.
The definition can be done within \renewenvironment, note that you need double ## for the argument because it is not an argument of the environment but of a command defined within the environment.
Some extra consideration should be done in case there is no footnote. You can define the command to show the stored contents to do nothing by default, and redefine that as well if \footnote is used (note how untidy it is...).
MWE
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{needspace}
\let\origfootnote\footnote
\renewenvironment{quote}
               {
               \list{\Large\glqq\hspace{-0.4em} \normalsize} 
               {\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item\relax\small\sl\ignorespaces
                \needspace{4\baselineskip}%
                \gdef\fnshowcontents{\relax}%
                \def\footnote##1{\gdef\fnstoredcontents{##1}\gdef\fnshowcontents{\origfootnote{\fnstoredcontents}}}%
                }
               {\Large\grqq\normalsize\fnshowcontents\endlist}

\begin{document} 


\lipsum[1]

\begin{quote}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{citationsreference}
\end{quote}

Regular footnote\footnote{printed immediately} as before.

\begin{quote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{quote}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}

Result:


Thanks! Your untidy solution works perfectly

Note that any footnotes inside the quote wiill be moved to the end.

Indeed, and if there is more than one footnote inside a quote then only the last one will be shown.
